# Can't get my POST AJAX call to work

Tags: jquery, post

I'm trying to send the following AJAX request, but it seams I have a bug somewhere and I can't find it.

```
var ajaxcontent = {};
ajaxcontent['cieID'] = $("select[name='select']",CurrForm).val();
ajaxcontent['action'] = "ConfigGetProviderList";
$.post("ajax/action1.php", ajaxcontent, 
    function(data, status) {
    if(status == "success") {
        var request = $.parseJSON(data);
        $("tbody",CurrForm).html(request.page);
    }
}
```

This function should be calling a HTML form from a outside file ("myForm.HTML") and be inserted by my JS code.

If I log ( console.log(); ) the var "ajaxcontent[]" I have all the right value in it.

I had already called the "ajax/action1.php" with a $_POST['action']= 'ConfigGetProviderList'; from a php script and I get the proper response. Therefore I know my action1.php is OK. When I take this code out of my .js file, my js script work fine. So I've narrowed the error to this bit of code.

This code should update the content of a HTML form (the tbody) once the MySQL database has been updated.

I'm a little confuse, can anyone give my a pointer in the right direction?

Comment: so what exactly is happening.  How have you tried to debug this?

Comment: More information would be helpful. What does it do right now? What should it do? Are there any logs you can show us? What does `ajax/action1.php` look like?

Comment: I'm no AJAX expert - But shouldn't $.post("ajax/action1.php", ajaxcontent, have a closing bracket?

Comment: Hey there, Daniel. It looks like this post is missing a little info.

The four basic things are:
- What have you done?
- What do you want to happen?
- What is happening?
- How have you tried to fix it?

You've got the "What have you done" part down: we can see your code.  The next steps are to post the errors you're receiving or the behavior that is unexpected, a short summary of what you EXPECTED to happen, and the steps you've taken to fix the issue yourself.

This will keep everyone from taking random shots in the dark.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi, this js file don't run at all with this code, but if I comment the code and place a "console.log('test');" The function run's properly. I mitchzirra Actually found the answer, I was missing a closing ");" on the $.POST call, and that frose up my script.

Comment: Asking for help doesn't deserve the -1..... The action1.php have above 900 lines. I've track the error sown to this part of code. Thank to mithchzirra, I've solve the issue. But again, you are quick on the -1....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a closing bracket on

```
$.post("ajax/action1.php", ajaxcontent,
```

Should be

```
$.post("ajax/action1.php", ajaxcontent)
```